# How to make where statement to match field from another model in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

How can i achieve thing like this in Laravel controller

```
$results = ModelA::with('model_b')->where('model_b.field_from_model_b',true)->get()
```

assuming that i have did the relation in the Model A like this

```
function model_b(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\ModelB');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `whereHas()` method if you want to filter `ModelA` by a field in `ModelB`:

```
ModelA::with('model_b')
    ->whereHas('model_b', function($q) {
        $q->where('field_from_model_b', true);
    })
    ->get();
```

If you just want to filter `ModelB` data:

```
ModelA::with(['model_b' => function($q) {
        $q->where('field_from_model_b', true);
    }])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the relation query this way.

```
$results = ModelA::with(['mobel_b' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('field_from_model_b', true);
}])
->get()
```